# Way to intercept emails on smtp docker (namshi/smtp)

Tags: docker, smtp

I am looking for a way to test the email sending feature of our app. I have configured namshi/smtp docker image to act as an smtp server and our app is using this smtp server to send emails. We currently have a system that reads the email on the client side once its delivered, to verify we are formatting the email correctly. This is a bit unreliable since it involves an actual email being delivered.

So, I wanted to see if there is a way to intercept or read emails being delivered through this local smtp server. I checked the logs of the smtp server but as expected, it doesn't have any details of the email body or subject. Anyone knows anyway I could intercept these smtp requests somehow?

Or if there is a better way to verify email formatting as part of integration testing?

Comment: Can't you mock the server in the sending code? Assemble the email and then pass it to a mock server that just saves it as a byte stream, which your test then checks? Keep the whole network out of the test.

Comment: Just realized that. I found a simple python non-blocking script using smtpd library is sufficient for this purpose. Thanks you.

Comment: And at some point if you want to make a manual test: your solutions are called [mailhog](https://hub.docker.com/r/mailhog/mailhog), [mailcatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/) or any of the like

Answer (score 0):

Heres a good source on how to use smtpd library in python to mock an SMTP server https://pymotw.com/2/smtpd/. Mock SMTP server and process emails through smtpd.SMTPServer.process_message